# Redirect folder with data

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

hi i read all of other questions but i cant resolve my problem.
i setup my joomla website in this `url: https://www.example.com/new`
and now i want reditect this to `(https://www.example.com)` with my data for example i want reditect `example.com/new/all-ads-smart/103-Hotels` or other to `example.com/all-ads-smart/103-Hotels`
also i test this but it dont work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this just work when i open `(https://www.example.com/new)` and redirect me to `(https://www.example.com)` and when open this `(https://www.example.com/new/ads.php)` i give 404 error

### in end i sorry for my bad english<3

my data is:

```
new/all-ads-smart/103-Hotels
```

to

```
/all-ads-smart/103-Hotels
```

Comment: Do you have any other directives / redirects? The code you have posted actually looks OK. This code wouldn't actually redirect `https://www.example.com/new` (since there is no trailing slash). Try clearing your browser cache (any erroneous 301 redirects you tried earlier will have been cached by the browser).

Comment: no I Check And Test With Private Browser in FireFox

Comment: Have you moved your entire site to the document root, so it's no longer in the `/new` subdirectory? Does the `/new` subdirectory still exist?

Comment: yes , i move my website from /new to my root directory and /new directory does exist still , and all of my data indexed by google and i should redirect all of my link But it takes a long time

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in the `/new` subdirectory that uses mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This actually looks OK and should "work", providing it is in the root `.htaccess` file and located near the top of that file. However, if you still have a `.htaccess` file in the `/new` subdirectory then this is likely to override the directive in the parent `.htaccess` file - so it won't do anything.

However, it would be preferable to do this in the `/new/.htaccess` file instead (and keep the parent `.htaccess` file *clean*). For example, remove everything in the existing `/new/.htaccess` file and simply have an unconditional redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will override the parent `.htaccess` file and when anyone visits the `/new` subdirectory they will be redirected. (This uses mod_rewrite, as opposed to a mod_alias `Redirect` to ensure that it overrides the parent `.htaccess` file.)